# Mark positions of a string in a list

Tags: python, string, list, dna-sequence

I have two lists,

one holds nucleotide values

```
nucleotides = ['A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'C']
```

second one holds true(1) or false(0) values for every letter to indicate that they are covered or not.

```
flag_map = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

initially second one have all false values.

Let's say I want to map every `"AGC"` values in the array.

So my second list should be like this:

```
flag_map = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

What is the best method that I can use here?

Comment: As for the answer, it could just have the sequence of nucleotides as a string and do a simple search and replace for `AGC` into 1 and then replace all the other characters with 0.

Comment: You might get some answers more suited to what you are looking for if you specify what you mean by "best method". Are you looking for speed? Simplicity? It might also help improve your question if you showed your method and explained why you think it isn't best, so people won't waste time thinking along that direction (or let you know if your method is indeed the best if it is)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could join your original list of characters into a single string, and then replace instances of `'AGC'` by `'111'`. Then iterate over each character in this string, and if it's `'1'`, we want a `1` in our result, else we want `0`.

I changed your variable name because `str` is a built-in.

```
nucleotides = ['A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'C']

flag_map = [int(char == '1') 
          for char in "".join(nucleotides).replace('AGC', '111')]
```

Which gives the desired result:

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

The `char == '1'` checks if the character is `'1'`, and `int(...)` converts the boolean `True` to `1` and `False` to `0`. If you are fine with booleans (for most applications I can see, you should be perfectly fine using `bool` instead of `int`) then you can skip the conversion to `int` and simply have `char == '1'`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P680OSc1vyQzJbVYwVYhWt1RXUdB3R1EOIOIEBCBEHNH5Tqrx3JxpeUkpsfnJhaAtGfmlWgkZyQWKdjaKqgbqmsqpOUXKYAFMvMUlJT0svIz8zSQrNTUK0otyElMTtVQd3QHW2hoCNQGNLWgCGQWzGzN//8B)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension like so:

```py
l = ['A','G','C','T','A','G','G','A','G','C']
s = "AGC"
res = [+(c in s and l[i - (j := s.index(c)) : i + len(s) - j] == [*s]) 
          for i, c in enumerate(l)]
```